# Validating dynamic generated textfied value with array value

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

how to check dynamically generated textfield value against predefined array value.I'm doing voucher code management system, where user can add multiple voucher number in text field by clicking n nof of add text field. how can I check dynamically generated textfield value against predefined value in array.

I found inarray in jquery. But I don't have idea how to use it against multiple text field.

I'm looking form validation similar to below link:
https://www.optimusdatum.com/site/?page_id=997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var categories = ["one", "two"];
$(document).on("change", "input[type=text]", function () {
  if ($.inArray($(this).val(), categories) > -1) {
        alert("match occured");
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/133/)

Since your text fields are created dynamically, you need to use `delegates` for binding the events.

Also you can use `$.inArray(` to check if the array contais a specific string. If the array doesnt contains string, it will return -1.

**Edit**

If you have multipe text fields, use like this

```
var categories = ["one", "two"];

$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    $("error").removeClass("error");
    $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), categories) < 0) {
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });

});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/146/)